# Django Migrations [ AttributeError: 'Startup' object has no attribute 'tags']

Tags: django, python-3.6

This is my model and migration file. Its from The book [Django-Unleashed](https://django-unleashed.com/) - Chapter 10 .

*Models.py:*

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    def get_update_url(self):
        return reverse('organizer_tag_update',
                       kwargs={'slug': self.slug})
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('organizer_tag_detail',kwargs={'slug':self.slug})
    def get_delete_url(self):
        return reverse('organizer_tag_delete',
                       kwargs={'slug': self.slug})

    name = models.CharField(
        max_length=31, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(
        max_length=31,
        unique=True,
        help_text='A label for URL config.'
        )
    class Meta:
        ordering=['name']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Startup(models.Model):

    class Meta:
        ordering=['name']
        get_latest_by=['founded_date']

    name = models.CharField(
        max_length=31, db_index=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(
        max_length=31,
        unique=True,
        help_text='A label for URL config.')

    description = models.TextField()
    founded_date = models.DateField('date founded')
    contact = models.EmailField()
    website = models.URLField(max_length=255)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag,blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
    def get_update_url(self):
         return reverse('organizer_startup_update',kwargs={'slug': self.slug})
    def get_delete_url(self):
         return reverse('organizer_startup_delete',kwargs={'slug': self.slug})
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('organizer_startup_detail',kwargs={'slug': self.slug})
```

**Migrations.py :**

```
#startup_data.py        SECOND MIGRATION FILE

from datetime import date
from django.db import migrations, models

STARTUPS = [
    {
        "name": "Arachnobots",
        "slug": "arachnobots",
        "contact": "contact@arachnobots.com",
        "description":
            "Remote-controlled internet-enabled "
            "Spider Robots.",
        "founded_date": date(2014, 10, 31),
        "tags": ["mobile", "augmented-reality"],
        "website":
            "http://frightenyourroommate.com/",
    },
    {
        "name": "Boundless Software",
        "slug": "boundless-software",
        "contact": "hello@boundless.com",
        "description": "The sky was the limit.",
        "founded_date": date(2013, 5, 15),
        "tags": ["big-data"],
        "website": "http://boundless.com/",
    },
]

def add_startup_data(apps, schema_editor):
    Startup = apps.get_model(
        'organiser', 'Startup')
    Tag = apps.get_model('organiser', 'Tag')
    for startup in STARTUPS:
        startup_object = Startup.objects.create(
            name=startup['name'],
            slug=startup['slug'],
            contact=startup['contact'],
            description=startup['description'],
            founded_date=startup['founded_date'],
            website=startup['website'])
        for tag_slug in startup['tags']:
            startup_object.tags.add(
                Tag.objects.get(
                    slug=tag_slug))
def remove_startup_data(apps, schema_editor):
    Startup = apps.get_model(
        'organiser', 'Startup')
    for startup in STARTUPS:
        startup_object = Startup.objects.get(
            slug=startup['slug'])
        startup_object.delete()
class Migration(migrations.Migration):
     dependencies = [
        ('organiser', '0002_tag_data'),
    ]
     operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(
            add_startup_data,
            remove_startup_data)
    ]

#tagdata.py      FIRST MIGRATION FILE

TAGS = (
    # ( tag name, tag slug ),
    ("augmented reality", "augmented-reality"),
    ("big data", "big-data"),
    ("django", "django"),
    ("education", "education"),
    ("ipython", "ipython"),
    ("javascript", "javascript"),
    ("jupyter", "jupyter"),
    ("mobile", "mobile"),
    ("node.js", "node-js"),
    ("php", "php"),
    ("python", "python"),
    ("ruby on rails", "ruby-on-rails"),
    ("ruby", "ruby"),
    ("video games", "video-games"),
    ("web", "web"),
    ("zend", "zend"),
)

def add_tag_data(apps,schema_editor):
    Tag=apps.get_model('organiser','Tag')
    for tag_name,tag_slug in TAGS:
        Tag.objects.create(
        name=tag_name,
        slug=tag_slug
        )
def remove_tag_data(apps,schema_editor):
    Tag=apps.get_model('organiser','Tag')
    for _,tag_slug in TAGS:
        tag=Tag.objects.get(slug=tag_slug)
        tag.delete()

class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('organiser', '0001_initial'),
    ]

    operations = [
    migrations.RunPython(
                add_tag_data,
                remove_tag_data )
    ]
```

Full Error :

> migrations\0003_startup_data.py", line 1 13, in add_startup_data
>       startup_object.tags.add( AttributeError: 'Startup' object has no attribute 'tags'

The error appears when i try to run `migrate` command.

Comment: How many migrations you're currently having? In which one the Tag model was defined?

Comment: I have 5 migrations including initial.py...Tag is defined in two of them i.e tag_data.py and startup_data.py (the one i included )

Comment: So the migration operation which creates model Tag is in `0001_initial.py`, isn't it?

Comment: The first thought that comes to my mind is the migration file which adds field `tags` into model `Startup` is created after `0003_startup_data.py`

Comment: Thank You..I found the error

Comment: If you merge the two migrations (set the dependencies of `startup_data` to `0001_inital` and run `makemigrations --merge`), or just swap the order of those two files, do the error still occurs?

Comment: Great, could you please update into your post

Comment: I just found that AddField for Startup model was missing in initial.py..i added it manually and that solved the problem

Comment: Cool, if you think my suggestion useful in some way, it would be great if there is an upvote :p

Answer (score 0):

Adding this in 0001_initial.py solved it...

```
operations = [
........ # other code here
migrations.AddField(
        model_name='startup',
        name='tags',
        field=models.ManyToManyField(to='organiser.Tag'),
    ),
]
```